# Apache Cayenne not invalidating objects

Tags: java, maven, apache-cayenne

After updating to Apache Cayenne version 4.1 (from 4.0) objects don't get invalidated and reloaded as they did before. For example, if I open my application on two browser windows and modify something in one window, the other window doesn't get updated. Before I made the update this was the case.

After reading UPGRADE.txt I taught it may be because of CAY-2262 or CAY-2259, so I tried to include `cayenne-cache-invalidation` in my pom.xml. That didn't change anything. However, it seems like an caching problem, because if I manually reload the second site it works again.

Maybe someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this on my own, it seems that the default parameter of `SERVER_CONTEXTS_SYNC_PROPERTY` changed.

My problem was fixed by setting:

```
 Java -Dcayenne.server.contexts_sync_strategy=true
```